# Python based job scheduler with dependency resolution

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python based job scheduler which has job dependency resolution (may be specified in XML format). The existing ones mostly kick-off jobs at certain times but don't resolve dependencies between the jobs i.e. job Z which is dependent on job X and Y should only kick-off after successful completion of X & Z.

This is expected to run on 64-bit Windows. The less the dependencies/installation requirements, the better.

Comment: IPython's parallel computing framework handles task dependencies: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/index.html

Comment: IPython is more towards managing jobs across multiple nodes - quite heavy duty to be frank :) My requirement is more focused on running jobs (executable/DOS commands) on the same box but being able to handle job dependencies.

Comment: It's perfectly capable of running on a single box as well. I know it might not be exactly what you're looking for, but if you have to assemble something yourself, it might have some bits you can reuse.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to git a try to [RQ](http://python-rq.org/docs/).

> To execute a job that depends on another job, use the depends_on
>   argument:
>
> ```
> q = Queue('low', async=False) 
> report_job = q.enqueue(generate_report)
> q.enqueue(send_report, depends_on=report_job)
> ```
>
> The ability to handle job dependencies allows you to split a big job
>   into several smaller ones. A job that is dependent on another is
>   enqueued only when it's dependency finishes successfully.

Comment: RQ workers only run on operating systems that provide `fork()` though, so not on Windows. See the [Limitations](http://python-rq.org/docs/) section at the very bottom.

Comment: oops I had missed the constraint @user29981 about Windows. indeed. Thanks Lukas.